# jQuery: Tooltip Positioning

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to figure out how to properly center a tooltip under a link (so it's not positioned in line with the link).

```
                   [Link]
      [tooltip should appear like this]

                   [Link]
                   [tooltip should not appear like this]
```

I'm also trying to figure out why my tooltip is not fading in.

http://jsfiddle.net/fj4xz/

Comment: I updated it, is that what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/fj4xz/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There :

```
$('a.tooltip').hover(function() {
    var title = $(this).attr('title');
    var offset=$(this).offset();
    var width=$(this).outerWidth();
    var height=$(this).outerHeight();
    $content=$('<div class="tooltip">' + title + '</div>').fadeIn();
    $(this).append($content);
    var middle = offset.left+(width-$content.outerWidth())/2;
    // middle = Math.max(offset.left,offset.left+(width-$content.outerWidth())/2 );
    $content.offset({ top: offset.top+height, left: middle });
    $('div.tooltip').hover(function() {
        $(this).fadeOut('fast');            
    });
}, function() {
    $(this).find('div').fadeOut('fast');
});
```

​
You can make the code more readable, but the idea is there ;)

[EDIT] Code changed, the text has to be centered even if it is too long. (I misread the question)

Comment: This centered the short tooltip, but when you hover over "test" with the longer tooltip, it didn't center it. Ideas?

Comment: Oh sorry, that's a functionnality! Didn't read correctly! I change my code ;)